# How to troubleshoot a schema issue in Hibernate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate

I'm playing with Hibernate a little bit. I created a "Group" class and a XML schema tied to it. Unfortunately when I try to export that schema, my .NET complains about a syntax error. I'm pretty sure my schema is malformed, but is there any technique to help troubleshooting ?

My XML schema looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
               assembly="Folke"
               namespace="Folke.Code.Domain">
  <class name="Group">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="native"></generator>
    </id>
    <property name="SiteId" />
    <property name="Name" index="GroupName"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

ASP.NET complains that there's a syntax error here:

```
new SchemaExport(HibernateModule.CurrentConfiguration).Execute(false, true, false, false);
```

The syntax error being "near Group" I'm pretty sure the problem is in the Group schema, but, again, I have no idea where to look to get a bit more details.

Comment: BTW, `hibernate` tag is normally used for (java) Hibernate; NHibernate has its own `nhibernate` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the `Group` table name you can quote it using the backtick character in the `table` attribute of your class mapping. eg:

```
<class name="Group" table="`Group`">
```

This will result in the table name being quoted in whatever dialect you are using when the SQL is generated. eg `[Group]` in MSSQL T-Sql or `"Group"` in DB2 SQL.

Answer (score 2):

"Group" is a reserved word in SQL (part of `GROUP BY` clause name).

Consider either naming your class differently or explicitly specifying different table name via `table` attribute in `class` mapping:

```
<class name="Group" table="MyGroups">
```

Comment: Ding ding ding, we have a winner.